# How to customize the Process button on the AP505200 screen. Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

What method should I use to customize the "process" button on the AP 505200 screen.
I need to record records in a certain table when I press the Process button

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is mapped to the Process/Process All actions using the SetProcessDelegate method of the processing data view.

First locate the Graph of the AP505200 screen (APReleaseChecks):
[image]

In the Source Code screen search for APReleaseChecks graph and find the SetProcessDelegate method:
[image]

```
APPaymentList.SetProcessDelegate(list => ReleasePayments(list, action));
```

The process delegate ReleasePayments method is static so you can't easily override it.
Try using SetProcessDelegate to call your own process delegate that will in turn call the base one.

```
public class APReleaseChecks_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APReleaseChecks>
{
    public virtual void ReleaseChecksFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseChecksFilter filter = e.Row as ReleaseChecksFilter;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            Base.APPaymentList.SetProcessDelegate(delegate (List<APPayment> list)
            {
                // Do processing on list items before base process delegate
                // [...]

                // Call base process delegate
                APReleaseChecks.ReleasePayments(list, filter.Action);

                // Do processing on list items after base process delegate
                // [...]
            });
        }
    }
}
```